# Logstash 1.4.2 grok filter: _grokparsefailure

Tags: logstash-grok

1. i am trying to parse this log line:
   ***-  2014-04-29 13:04:23,733 [main] INFO  (api.batch.ThreadPoolWorker) Command-line options for this run:***
   here's the logstash config file i use:

```html
input {
        stdin {}
}

filter {
 grok {
    match => [ "message", " - %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time} \[%{WORD:main}\] %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} %{JAVACLASS:class} %{DATA:mydata} "]
  }

    date {
    match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
  }

output {
  elasticsearch {
    host => "localhost"
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Here's the output i get:

```html
{
       "message" => " - 2014-04-29 13:04:23,733 [main] INFO (api.batch.ThreadPoolWorker) Commans run:",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2015-02-02T10:53:58.282Z",
          "host" => "NAME_001.corp.com",
          "tags" => [
        [0] "_grokparsefailure"
    ]
}
```

Please if anyone can help me find where the problem is on the gork pattern.
I tried to parse that line in http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ but it parses only the timestamp, %{WORD} and %{LOGLEVEL} the rest is ignored!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two error in your config.

**First**

The error in `GROK` is the `JAVACLASS`, you have to include `(` `)` in the pattern, For example:  `\(%{JAVACLASS:class}\`.

**Second**

The `date` filter `match` have two value, first is the `field` you want to parse, so in your example it is `time`, not `timestamp`. The second value is the date pattern. You can refer to [here](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/date#match)

Here is the config

```
input {
        stdin {

        }
}

filter {
        grok {
                match => [ "message", " - %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time} \[%{WORD:main}\] %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} \(%{JAVACLASS:class}\) %{GREEDYDATA:mydata}"
                ]
        }
        date {
                match => [ "time" , "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS" ]
        }
}

output
{
        stdout {
                codec => rubydebug
        }
}
```

FYI. Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thank you Ben for your feedback. I already tried your solution adding \(%{JAVACLASS:class}\ doesn't solve the problem. The pattern JAVACLASS actually works fine when I use it alone in the match pattern it extracts the java class: 
{...
      "class" => "api.batch.ThreadPoolWorker"
} 
But when i add the rest of the patterns along with the JAVACLASS it gives me grokparsefailure error tag. I tested the other patterns they work fine too it's just combining all of them together with JAVACLASS that creates an error. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Your log sample worked on my config. And JAVACLASS pattern is : \\(%{JAVACLASS:class}\\) , include the `\\`. Please have a try with my config.

Comment: I tried again after deleting all failed logs from elasticsearch and it worked now. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Actually i need to parse a log file that contains thousands of lines of logs those have the same format of the line i showed before and sometimes with java stack trace. but when i added this line to my file entry ** -  2014-04-29 13:04:23,700 [main] INFO (api.batch.ThreadPoolWorker) Loading properties from classpath resource file:/prop/env3/logiciels/jkl/nnh/devprint/splapp/standalone/config/threadpoolworker.properties**
it parsed only the first line that i was testing with and not the above one. is this pattern supposed to parse my whole log file? or it would break once it finds a match?

Comment: You have to use the multiline pattern. Please have a look. http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/multiline. If you have another problem, please kindly ask another question. :)

Comment: i tried the multiline config. can you please take a look at it and tell me what's wrong:
input {
       # stdin {}
  file {
   path => "/root/test2.log"
   start_position => "beginning"
  }}
filter {
multiline {
      pattern => " ^-%{SPACE}%{SPACE}%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}"
       negate => true
       what => "previous"
   }
 grok {
    match => [ "message", " -%{SPACE}%{SPACE}%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time} \[%{WORD:main}\] %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}%{SPACE}%{SPACE}\(%{JAVACLASS:class}\) %{GREEDYDATA:mydata}"]
  }
    date {
    match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
  }
}

Comment: the file i use contain these lines:
 -  2014-04-29 13:04:23,530 [main] INFO  (api.batch.ThreadPoolWorker) Command-line options for this run:
 -  2014-04-29 13:04:23,700 [main] INFO  (api.batch.ThreadPoolWorker) Loading properties from classpath resource file:/logiciels/ccnb//splapp/standalone/config/threadpoolworker.properties
 -  2014-01-14 11:09:38,623 [main] ERROR (support.context.ContextFactory) Error getting connection to database jdbc:oracle:thin:, with user cisuser and driver oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28001: the password has expired